# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidatingXMLObject

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-axis, jboss6.x

I am using axis2.war in my ear and I am packing all my jars in APP-INF and pointing them from the of axis2/META-INT/Manifest.in[Class-Path]. I am using ws security.

When I am request it from axis2 client I got the below error.

> > 12:55:05,359 INFO  [STDOUT] [ERROR]
> >     org/opensaml/xml/validation/ValidatingXMLObject 12:55:05,359 INFO 
> >     [STDOUT] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> >     org/opensaml/xml/validation/ValidatingXMLObject 12:55:05,360 INFO 
> >     [STDOUT]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
> >     12:55:05,360 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
> >     12:55:05,360 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) 12:55:05,360
> >     INFO  [STDOUT]     at
> >     org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:52)
> >     12:55:05,360 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
> >     org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:650)
> >     12:55:05,360 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
> >     org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:609)
> >     12:55:05,360 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
> >     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> >     12:55:05,361 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
> >     org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:608)
> >     12:55:05,361 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
> >     org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:585)
> >     12:55:05,361 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
> >     org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:156)
> >     12:55:05,361 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
> >     org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.doLoadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:141)
> >     12:55:05,361 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
> >     org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:132)
> >     12:55:05,361 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
> >     org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:461)
> >     12:55:05,362 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
> >     org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:262)
> >     12:55:05,362 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
> >     org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:161)
> >     12:55:05,362 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
> >     org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:280)
> >     12:55:05,362 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
> >     org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1172)
> >     12:55:05,362 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
> >     org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886)
>
> 12:55:05,362 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505)
>   12:55:05,362 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450)
>   12:55:05,363 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) 12:55:05,365
>   INFO  [STDOUT]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native
>   Method) 12:55:05,366 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
>   12:55:05,367 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) 12:55:05,369
>   INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:52)
>   12:55:05,370 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:650)
>   12:55:05,372 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:609)
>   12:55:05,373 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   12:55:05,374 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:608)
>   12:55:05,375 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:585)
>   12:55:05,376 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:156)
>   12:55:05,377 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.doLoadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:141)
>   12:55:05,378 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:132)
>   12:55:05,379 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:461)
>   12:55:05,380 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:262)
>   12:55:05,381 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:161)
>   12:55:05,382 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:280)
>   12:55:05,384 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1172)
>   12:55:05,386 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886)
>   12:55:05,387 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505)
>   12:55:05,388 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450)
>   12:55:05,389 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) 12:55:05,390
>   INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:89)
>   12:55:05,391 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
>   12:55:05,392 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313) 12:55:05,393 INFO
>   [STDOUT]     at
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
>   12:55:05,394 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:168)
>   12:55:05,395 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
>   12:55:05,396 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
>   12:55:05,397 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
>   12:55:05,398 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   12:55:05,399 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324)
>   12:55:05,401 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
>   12:55:05,403 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>   12:55:05,404 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>   12:55:05,405 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181)
>   12:55:05,406 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285)
>   12:55:05,407 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261)
>   12:55:05,408 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88)
>   12:55:05,409 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100)
>   12:55:05,410 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
>   12:55:05,411 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   12:55:05,412 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
>   12:55:05,413 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   12:55:05,415 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53)
>   12:55:05,416 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)
>   12:55:05,417 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   12:55:05,419 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654)
>   12:55:05,420 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)
>   12:55:05,422 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) 12:55:05,423 INFO  [STDOUT]
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidatingXMLObject 12:55:05,424 INFO 
>   [STDOUT]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>   12:55:05,425 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   12:55:05,426 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>   12:55:05,427 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) 12:55:05,428
>   INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>   12:55:05,429 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) 12:55:05,430
>   INFO  [STDOUT]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>   12:55:05,431 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249) 12:55:05,432 INFO  [STDOUT]
>   at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:304)
>   12:55:05,433 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1172)
>   12:55:05,434 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886)
>   12:55:05,436 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505)
>   12:55:05,438 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450)
>   12:55:05,439 INFO  [STDOUT]     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) 12:55:05,440
>   INFO  [STDOUT]     ... 70 more

Note: In -verbose:class log org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidatingXMLObject is loaded from the xmltooling.jar and I am using jboss 6

[Loaded org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidatingXMLObject from vfs:/D:/maven/Server/jboss-6.1.0/server/default/deploy/bpms.ear/APP-INF/lib/xmltooling-1.2.0.jar/]

Comment: your statements are contradicting... you say ClassNotFoundException, but you class is loaded. Put stacktrace for someone to understand better

Comment: Same I too get confused.Will update the stacktrace soon

Comment: ahh so it is NoClassDefFoundError. Check if this helps you - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Comment: That link actually helps me understand the issue but I don't know which class provided the implementation for the ValidatingXMLObject, from which jar. Can any one help me on it.

Comment: Verify if you have correctly set the dependency for xmltooling jar. If doubt refer this - http://mavenhub.com/c/org/opensaml/xml/validation/validatingxmlobject

Comment: Problem solved after referring to http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/dependencies.html and Thanks to G V for his useful comment on NoClassDefFoundError caused by ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you have correctly set the dependency for xmltooling.jar